# Avoid going to the database for every for loop iteration

Tags: django

I want to export data to Excel file in Django. First I get all members:

```
members_list = Member.objects\
            .exclude(deleted=True) \
            .annotate(num_calculations=Count('user__calculations'))\
            .order_by("-user__date_joined")
```

then I loop through members and add them to an excel file:

```
for row in members_list:
            row_num += 1
            ws.write(row_num, 0, row.number or "", font_style)
            ws.write(row_num, 1, row.user.first_name or "", font_style)
            ws.write(row_num, 2, row.user.last_name or "", font_style)
            ws.write(row_num, 3, row.address or "", font_style)
            col_num = 3
            for calculation in calculations_per_month_last_12_months(row.number):
                col_num += 1
                ws.write(row_num, col_num, calculation['total_calculations'] or "", font_style)
```

The function `calculations_per_month_last_12_months` is as follows:

```
items = list(Calculations.objects
                 .filter(user__member__number=member_number)
                 .filter(price_date__gte=datetime.datetime.now().today() - relativedelta(months=12))
                 .annotate(date=TruncMonth('price_date'))
                 .values('date')
                 .annotate(total=Count('id'))
                 .values('date', 'total')
                 .order_by('date'))

    result = []
    for month in range(12):
        date = timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=month)

        month_results = list(filter(lambda i: date <= i['date'] + relativedelta(months=1) < (date + relativedelta(months=1)), items))

        month_result = 0

        if month_results:
            month_result = month_results[0]['total']

        result.append({
            'total_calculations': month_result
        })

    return result
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is if I have a large number of members.

The `calculations_per_month_last_12_months` function goes to the database for every member. That is what I don't want.

If I have for example 5000 members, then it will go 5000 times to the database.

Any advice how could I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prefetch_related` to grab all of the calculations in the original query. It essentially performs a SQL join so that it all becomes one query. I also added `select_related('user')` to avoid the additional query for the member's user's names.

```
members_list = Member.objects\
        .exclude(deleted=True) \
        .annotate(num_calculations=Count('user__calculations'))\
        .order_by("-user__date_joined")\
        .select_related("user")\
        .prefetch_related("user__calculations")
```

Then in your function, you can pass in the `member` object and it already has the calcuations preloaded, so you can skip the additional query

```
def calculations_per_month_last_12_months(member):
    for month in range(12):
        date = timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=month)
        next_month = date + relativedelta(months=1)

        month_results = list(
            filter(
                lambda i: date <= i['date'] + relativedelta(months=1) < next_month,
                member.user.calculations
            )
        )

        month_result = 0

        if month_results:
            month_result = month_results[0]['total']

        yield {'total_calculations': month_result}
```

Edit: Also added the `yield` syntax to avoid allocating the extra space for the results list.